# Can I access local system env. variables when using vue-cli?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I'm using Vue-cli V3, In my UI I need to pass an environment variable that states if I'm in test mode or not.

I know I can use .env files to define variables, but I have a problem (that is related to our Jenkins build process) that prevents me from using it.

Is there a way to access system env variables?

Comment: Maybe fix the underlying problem with your Jenkins build process?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you access them the same way that you would inside any normal JS file.

```
// server.js
const port = process.env.PORT;
console.log(`Your port is ${port}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

**vue-cli** only processes environment variables with `VUE_APP` prefix, with `NODE_ENV` being an exception. Use environment variables with `VUE_APP_` prefix, only then it will work. If you have variable `TEST` make it `VUE_APP_TEST`.

```
const test = process.env.VUE_APP_TEST
console.log(test);
```

I was also struggling with the same problem it almost took an hour to solve this, finally found this document.
reference -
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#example-staging-mode